# Generate QtLabel inside Class and call it in MainWindow

Tags: qt, class, object, label, mainwindow

I'm pretty new to Qt and I came across a problem I don't find a fix for.

So my problem is as follows:

I try to generate a `QtLabel` inside a class and display it in my `mainWindow`.

```
class Hexagon
{
    public:
        QPolygon polygon;
        QLabel *cellText = new QLabel(this);

        Hexagon(int startX, int startY, int length, int row, int cell, char letters[26])
        {
            polygon <<
                        QPoint(startX, startY)
                    <<
                        QPoint(startX+length*qCos(qDegreesToRadians(30.0)), startY-length*qSin(qDegreesToRadians(30.0)))
                    <<
                        QPoint(startX+2*length*qCos(qDegreesToRadians(30.0)), startY)
                    <<
                        QPoint(startX+2*length*qCos(qDegreesToRadians(30.0)), startY+length)
                    <<
                        QPoint(startX+length*qCos(qDegreesToRadians(30.0)),  startY+length+length*qSin(qDegreesToRadians(30.0)))
                    <<
                        QPoint(startX, startY+length);

            cellText->setText(QString(QChar(letters[row])) + QString(QChar(letters[cell])));
            cellText->setGeometry(startX + 35, startY + 10, 40, 20);
            cellText->show();
        }
};
```

So there is my Hexagon class that creates a hexagon formed polygon that can be drawn later.
Now I try to add some QtLabel for each Cell (Hexagon) I have.

But I run into an error:

> widget.cpp:28: Fehler: no matching constructor for initialization of
> 'QLabel'

How can I fix this error and generate my Label inside my Class and extend the mainWindow with it?

Comment: use `QLabel *cellText = new QLabel()`

Comment: If I do that, it generates a new Window every time and does not extend my main window.

Comment: Is this the real code?  If you want your `Hexagon` instance to be the parent of its `QLabel` data member then `Hexagon` must, at the very least, inherit from `QObject`.  A [mcve] would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

the reason of the error is because you are using the QLabel constructor wrong

there is only

```
QLabel(QWidget *, Qt::WindowFlags )
QLabel(const QString &, QWidget *, Qt::WindowFlags )
```

and no

```
QLabel(Hexagon*)
```

thus, the line with

```
QLabel *cellText = new QLabel(this);
```

is not valid because of `this`